# BigQuery vs Custom Search for High-throughput Google (Scholar) Searches?

Tags: python, bigdata, google-bigquery, google-custom-search, google-search-api

For a list of ~30 thousand keywords, I'm trying to find out how many Google search hits there exist for each keyword, similar to this website but on a larger scale: http://azich.org/google/.

I am using python to query and was originally planning to use pygoogle. Unfortunately Google has a limit of ~100 searches a day for a free account. I am willing to use a paid service, but I am not sure which Google service makes more sense - BigQuery or Custom Search. Bigquery seems to be for searches on a provided set of data, whereas Custom Search seems to be website search solutions for a small "slice" of the internet.

Would someone refer me to the appropriate service that will allow me to perform the above task? It doesn't need to be a free service - I am willing to pay.

Two more things, if possible: I'd like the searches to be from Google Scholar, but this is not necessary. Second, I'd like to save the text from the front page, such as the blurbs from each search result, to text-mine the front page results.

Answer (score 4):

BigQuery is not a tool to interact with Google Search in any way. BigQuery is a tool for you to feed your data, and then run analytical queries over those data. But you need first to ingest the data.